# Sun Blade 150 with Solaris 8 stopped booting with "missing or bad passwd entry for <root>"

Tags: boot

I have screwed it up by deleted the first "/" in the /ect/passwd file for the root.  Now, the system won't boot all the way for me to login and correct the file.  it stopped after printing a few "missing or bad passwd entry for " Please help me with a way to fix the file while the system is not booting all the way.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you boot single-user? Hold down the `stop` and `a` keys right after powering on, then type `boot -sw`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to boot into recovery mode. Probably the easiest way to do this is to use installation media, *carefully*.

Lesson learned: don't mess with critical Unix files. If you do, make *thrice* sure everything is OK.